# Simple swipe gallery with jQTouch javascript iphone / ipad

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, jqtouch, extjs

What I wish to achieve is have a simple gallery of images which the user can swipe through using jQTouch ( http://jqtouch.com )

```
<div id="container">
<img src="1.gif">
<img src="2.gif">
<img src="3.gif">
</div>
```

The images are quite long, for example 200px in width each. The container itself is 300px wide with hidden overflow.

What I wish to happen is when the user swipes the galley container, it drags the images to the left/right.

So far I have set up the container to receive swipe events and which direction it is in, however to be honest I have completely no idea where to go on from there.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Agreed that the examples of use are plentiful but the actual exposure of code or any tutorials is sorely lacking!

Answer (score 8):

Have you come across [this demo](http://samshull.com/jqtouch-r148/demos/main/)?

"Photo Gallery" and "Photo Gallery 2" may be what you want. And if you just want to have photos and some captions, it should be fairly simple to setup:

```
jQT.generateGallery("pageID",
    [
    {src:"http://www.site.com/somepic.jpg"},
    {src:"pic1.jpg",caption:"Test Image 1"}
    ],
    {defaultIndex:1}
);
```

You'll need the the jQT photo extension: `jqt.photo.js` and `jqt.photo.css`.

Answer (score 6):

Check out this lightweight mobile slider I just released. [Swipe](http://bradbirdsall.com/post/10687800055/swipe-1-0-a-lightweight-mobile-slider) might be able to solve your problem :)

Comment: Very nice. I like that it's independent. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: A few minutes into this, and starting to think that jQTouch doesn't have a swipe effect..

Comment: Suggested edit for this one: _broken link_, _changed links to github + [swipejs.com](http://swipejs.com)_. However, suggestion was rejected by community. Now, community could get glue from this comment :)